# ReferenceError: admin is not defined

Tags: solidity, truffle

It happen when use truffle test,

[image]

here my contract file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


import "./DappToken.sol";


contract DappTokenSale {

    address payable admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice; 
    }
    function multiply (uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens (uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {

        require (msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require (tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require (tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));


        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
        function endSale () public {

            require (msg.sender == admin);
            require (tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
            selfdestruct(admin);
        }

    }
```

here my test js file:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require('./DappToken.sol');
var DappTokenSale = artifacts.require('./DappTokenSale.sol');

contract('DappTokenSale', function(accounts) {
    var tokenInstance;
    var tokenSaleInstance;
    var admin = accounts[0];
    var buyer = accounts[1]; 
    var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;
    var tokensAvailable = 750000;
    var numberOfTokens;

    it('Initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenSaleInstance.address
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has contract address");
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has token contract address");
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
        }).then(function(price) {
            assert.equal(price, tokenPrice, 'token price is correct');
        });
    });

    it('facilitates token buying', function(){
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return DappTokenSale.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance){
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, tokensAvailable, {from: admin})
        }).then(function(receipt){
            numberOfTokens = 10;
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens*tokenPrice})
        }).then(function(receipt) {
            assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Sell', 'should be the "Sell" event');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer, buyer, 'logs the account that purchased the tokens');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._amount, numberOfTokens, 'logs the number of tokens purchased');
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
        }).then(function(amount){
            assert.equal(amount.toNumber(), numberOfTokens, 'increments the number of tokens sold');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(buyer);
        }).then(function(balance) {
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
        }).then(function(balance){
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), tokensAvailable - numberOfTokens);
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: 1});
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei')
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(800000, {from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens*tokenPrice})
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'cannot purchased more than available token');
    });
});
    });

it('end token sale', function() {
    return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return DappTokenSale.deployed();
    }).then(function(instance){
        tokenSaleInstance = instance;
        return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({from:buyer });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
        return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({from: admin});
    }).then(function(receipt){
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'return all unsold dapp tokens to admin')
        return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    }).then(function(price) {
        assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0,'token price was reset')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `});` in your code. As you can see from the indentation you end up the `contract` part too early so the `admin` variable is no longer in the scope.

Just remove one `});` before *end token sale* and it should work as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's work !